# How to position the heart correctly in this card

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a digital valentines day card, where it opens up,etc and am trying to place the heart in the middle, right below surprise, so it's the first thing they see when the open it.I tried a lot of ways to fix it but they all don't work.I tried changing the heart's position as well as the cards, but none of them worked.Does anyone know how to fix it?

```css
.codepen-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #D9DCD6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.book {
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 2rem 3rem rgba(#000, .25);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #484e4a;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.page__1 {
  background-color: #0d5c63;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.page__1::after {
  content: "Neat, huh?";
  color: #eff0eb;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #424b54;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s 0.5s;
}

.page__2 {
  background-color: #baa898;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.page:hover .page__1 {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  box-shadow: 1.5rem 2rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.page:hover .page__1::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.heart-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
}

.heart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite alternate;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: -10px 6px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.heart:before {
  left: 44%;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(225deg);
}

.heart:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(-225deg);
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.heart:hover:before,
.heart:hover:after {
  background-color: unset;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.heart:hover:before {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}

.heart:hover:after {
  border: 2px dashed #ffbf00;
}
```

```html
<div class="codepen-wrapper">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page__1">
        <p>Hover to open</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page__2">
        <p>Surprise!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heart-container">
        <div class="heart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please update your title with the issue/question and not just a plea

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: CSS can be tricky - just move things around as required

Comment: You have a LOT of excess CSS in here that can be removed with a few small updates.
The real answer is 1 line of CSS here once that removal and small set of changes is done but posting an answer is currently disallowed as this is closed....

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/css-shapes-the-heart

Comment: Nice article @TemaniAfif.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.codepen-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #D9DCD6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.book {
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 2rem 3rem rgba(#000, .25);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #484e4a;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.page__1 {
  background-color: #0d5c63;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.page__1::after {
  content: "Neat, huh?";
  color: #eff0eb;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #424b54;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s 0.5s;
}

.page__2 {
  background-color: #baa898;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.page__2 p{
 position: relative;
 top:75px
}
.page:hover .page__1 {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  box-shadow: 1.5rem 2rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.page:hover .page__1::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.heart-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;

}

.heart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 45px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite alternate;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: -10px 6px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.heart:before {
  left: 44%;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(225deg);
}

.heart:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(-225deg);
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.heart:hover:before,
.heart:hover:after {
  background-color: unset;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.heart:hover:before {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}

.heart:hover:after {
  border: 2px dashed #ffbf00;
}
```

```html
<div class="codepen-wrapper">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page__1">
        <p>Hover to open</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page__2">
        <p>Surprise!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heart-container">
        <div class="heart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps add a detailed explanation of the change and how that change works.

Answer (score 0):

You had a lot of extra CSS which I deleted.  Key here is where I moved your element just to the left after I did that CSS reduction with a negative margin `margin-left: -1em;`
I put some ugly borders on just to show what is where.

```css
.codepen-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #D9DCD6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.book {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 2rem 3rem rgba(#000, .25);
  color: #484e4a;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}

.page {
  perspective: 1500px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}

.heart-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
}

.heart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite alternate;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ffff00;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: -10px 6px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.heart:before {
  left: 44%;
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(225deg);
}

.heart:after {
  transform: scale(-1) rotate(-225deg);
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.heart:hover:before,
.heart:hover:after {
  background-color: unset;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.heart:hover:before {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}

.heart:hover:after {
  border: 2px dashed #ffbf00;
}
```

```html
<div class="codepen-wrapper">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page__1">
        <p>Hover to open</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page__2">
        <p>Surprise!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heart-container">
        <div class="heart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created this before some updates but this still shows the heart moved